# How to get user password expiration date from Active Directory?

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, passwords, samba

folks!

There are an Active Directory (Windows) and a Linux samba client. At the Active Directory the policy had adjusted in a such way so users need to change his passwords periodically (passwords have an expiration time).

My question is pretty simple: can I get this expiration time for the given user if I work on the Linux machine with the Samba?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on the configuration of the domaincontroller. You can try:

```
net ads user info USERNAME@DOMAIN.COM -S DC_SERVER_NAME -U USERNAME
```

where USERNAME@DOMAIN.COM is the account to gather info from, DC_SERVER_NAME is the hostname of your domain controller and USERNAME is your username.

You will be prompted for your domain password.

Now you get either information to your account, including expiry date of your password or you get

```
ads_pull_uint32 failed
```

in this case, your domain controller is not configured to provide account information to UNIX like systems.

You may contact your domain administrator to convince him to install and configure [Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_Services_for_UNIX) so that this command gives you the needed information.

This answer might be frustrating. It is for me as I am in the same situation and researched the topic a lot.

My workaround: I set a calendar reminder 80 days in the future, when I set my domain password (smbpasswd -U USERNAME -r DC_SERVER_NAME), since it expires every 90 days. Not perfect, but workable.

**[UPDATE]**
I found a way to determine the expiration date of your domain password with rpcclient, here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# author: Tim Wahrendorff 2016
# licence: Public Domain - https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Public_domain
# 
# To use this script you need at least: 
# sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin rpcclient
#
# Please set your account, password and domaincontroller to use this script


USER="username" # Domain accountname
PASS="Pa$$W0rd" # Domain password
DC="vmdc01"     # Domaincontroller

### START RPCCLIENT query
if [ "x$USERDCID" == "x" ]; then
    RPCLOOKUPID=$(rpcclient -U $USER%$PASS -c "lookupnames $USER" $DC 2> ./rpc_errFile)

    USERDCID=$(echo "$RPCLOOKUPID" | grep -e '[0-9]\{4,9\} ' -o)
fi

QUERYUSER=$(rpcclient -U $USER%$PASS -c "queryuser $USERDCID" $DC 2> ./rpc_errFile)

EXPDATE=$(echo "$QUERYUSER" | grep 'Password must change Time' | grep -e '[a-Z]\{2\}, [0-9]\{2\} [a-Z]\{3\} [0-9]\{4\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' -o)

## Load rpc error Message
RPCERR=$(<./rpc_errFile)

## send notifications to Unity Desktop
if [ "x$RPCERR" != "x" ]; then
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/dialog-error.png "Error while fetching expiration date of your domain password" "$RPCERR"    
else
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/dialog-information.png "your domain password expires at " "$EXPDATE h"
fi

### END RPCCLIENT query
```

I configured this script to run on autostart, I shows me when my domain password will expire in a Unity notification. Feel free to extend, improve and republish this script, it is public domain.

[/UPDATE]

Comment: Thank you. I got the failure answer in my case.

Comment: The cause for NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED may be in your smb.conf. in my smb.conf, the only thing that differs from default is these addde two lines:   
   idmap uid = 10000-20000
   idmap gid = 10000-20000

Comment: rpcclient seems not to be a package, install smbclient package instead, it includes rpcclient.

Comment: I've just tested queryuser command using username, instead of userdcid, and just worked. Btw, userdcid calculation was empty in my domain.

Comment: If you don't know your DC, you can find it by doing an SRV record lookup for _ldap._tcp.domain (and you can find the domain/realm from Samba config, e.g. /etc/samba/smb.conf), e.g. with `dig -t srv _ldap._tcp.domain`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on rpc client. However your regex gave 0 output for me. I think it is because "[a-Z]" is not recognized by bash (at least the version I am using 4.4.12). Also the number of values appeared to be off (example [a-Z\{2\} did not work, as the day appears as 3 letters). 
This maybe code rot, not sure. However I adjusted. Below is what I used and it worked for me.
Replace Line 24 with
`EXPDATE=$(echo "$QUERYUSER" | grep 'Password must change Time' | grep -e '[A-Za-z]\{3\}, [0-9]\{2\} [A-Za-z]\{3\} [0-9]\{4,\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\} [A-Z]\{3\}' -o)`

Comment: True, I had to adapt the regex myself, since my Company has set all the passwords to not expire anymore until the corona homeoffice is over.

One might want to look at the rpcclient output directly to determine the correct regex to use, if the given regex won't work.

Comment: @mondjunge, I have been messing around with the script more.
My big problem right now is rpcclient is slow.. as its setting up a tcp scoket for every query. My script is passing an array of all users. Do you know of a way to query a samba4 db directly for "Password must change time"? Or pass a list of users with rpcclient? the net ads commands did not work for me.

Comment: Well its been close to a year, but I figured out how to use rpcclient faster!
Create a command deck (text file) with "queryuser <username>" for every user you want to look up, then use `rpcclient -U $USER%$PASS $DC <.users.txt`. This is MUCH faster then establishing a tcp connection each time.

Comment: @Dave: nice one, mate!

Comment: Simple and manual version of the second part: `rpcclient -U my_username -c "queryuser target_username" dc_hostname`. Use `-U my_username%password` to avoid interactive pwd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

On linux you can use pdbedit

```
pdbedit -L -v -u <username>
```

And look for the line: Password must change

Comment: This does not work with samba4. Performing a 'samba-tool domain passwordsettings set --max-pwd-age=90' forced all my users to change their passwords (As all accounts are older than 90 days). 'pdbedit' still shows "Password must change: never" while rpcclient shows the updated date / time. More info found here
https://groups.google.com/g/linux.samba/c/D9n62kaiN14

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kerberos tickets, *ADpassword* is a simple python app to check password expiration and ask users to change it.

[ADpassword in GitHub](https://github.com/alfem/adpassword)